# Is there any working sand generator in Minecraft version 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Subject.
Using a shovel to obtain lots of sand (like for TNT) ruins the landscape, so it would be really, really nice to be able to get it by the good old generator. Using Google for queries like "Minecraft Sand Generator 1.7.10" only points me to some threads in which the OP asks for one, but gets nothing.

If that's important, I need it to create a lot of TNT for stuff like TNT cannons and sometimes glass for construction purposes.

Were there any unfixed designs left in the version 1.7.10?
If not, what was the last version to have a working sand generator?

Comment: I believe there were a few that worked in 1.7.4, I thought they were all fixed by 1.7.10 though, could be wrong

Comment: There are some. Use Google to find them, please. This site is for help for specific problems you encounter with your project, not for complete tutorials.

Comment: @Fabian Could you please share them as an answer? I did not find any solutions by googling. If you want, I can add the purpose that I need the generator for, which is producing a lot of glass and, mainly, TNT, but this seems to be rather irrelevant, as a specific problem (finding a working sand generator that works in a specific version) is stated already.

Comment: Yes, I could, but I won't. I already voted to close this question as "too broad", because it's not one that fits the scope of this Q&A site. About Google, look here, please: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Minecraft+1.7.10+sand+duplicator

Comment: @Fabian The first link is a thread with a similar request, but with people simply replying that all the bugs that allowed sand generators to exists were fixed in 1.7.10, even though some were present in 1.7.4. The other links are generators 1.7.4, which I am not using, my server runs on 1.7.10.

Comment: [[Meta discussion link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12981/what-is-the-problem-with-my-question-about-sand-generators-in-minecraft-1-7-10)]

Comment: @Fabian in the future, don't use lmgtfy links in comments. It's a banned link on StackOverflow because it's actually quite rude and unhelpful (I'm actually surprised it wasn't filtered out here).

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR: "Cheat" in some Sand

I spent the last few days rethinking my reasons to need a sand generator, which were:

- A need for really large amounts of Sand for TNT and Glass
- A wish to keep the natural terrain

At some moment I had a thought in my head: "Why don't I just use a command to give myself a needed amount of Sand?".

In original vanilla Minecraft, the problem with acquiring large amounts of Sand is not that it takes time, like with Diamonds (if not concerned about destroying terrain and armed with a Diamond Shovel, one can dig large stacks of Sand very quickly), and not the difficulty, like with the Nether Star. It's about terrain preservation.

So, my solution was to use something to give players large amounts of Sand for nothing:

- Giving Sand away via commands on demand
- Setting up a Command Block
- For a role-playing server, setting up a  Custom NPC that gives large amounts of Sand for a token amount of currency.
- Etc.!

While it might be cool to find a glitch that could solve the problem and build a fancy redstone scheme, I don't see any real problems rising from Sand, an already common resource, becoming more easily available. Actually, pretty much the same could go for other common and easy to obtain resources like wood (as not all the players replant their chopped down trees).

Comment: This may be the solution you went with, but this does not answer the question you originally asked. Your question is "Is there any working sand generator in Minecraft version 1.7.10?" where the answer can only be no or yes followed by an expansion on the answer. If you're fine with cheating, go right ahead, but this is not a sufficient answer to your question.  Don't get my wrong, this is a beautiful answer, but it's the answer to a different problem.

Comment: @Diriector_Doc Well, my problem was that I need large amounts of sand, and wanted a sand generator as a solution. I've soon understood that there is a better solution, which is injecting more Sand by external means. I know that for some people it can be more interesting to build a generator or to mine stuff by hand, but I don't feel like the game's balance gets broken if really common resources become completely free. Don't get me wrong: I see your point! But frame challenge answers are sometimes right, at least to me, at least at this moment. :)

Comment: I think this is perfectly reasonable. It's not uncommon for OP to ask a _too specific_ question and the answer to show them a different way.